# Pedagogue or Tyrant

Tags: discussion, undergraduate

How can someone ask a question regarding research in academia without being accused of "shopping"? To my knowledge, academia is a broad category that covers many topics with education. Dedicated to research, education, and scholarship. So it would seem to be a reasonable conclusion to post a question asking for articles or sites for research on a thread for academia. To me it seems that academia has become a group of self righteous, condescending, tyrants who refuse to help anyone who has a question unless it fit into "their mold". So is academia filled with pedagogues? No. Academia is filled with hypocritical tyrants. End Rant. Ban me if necessary, put the post on hold or close it. It will only prove my point more.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like all sites in the Stack Exchange network, this community *focuses* on the subset of questions that we believe we have the expertise to answer really well. Therefore, questions that are outside the scope of this site will be put on hold.

In particular, although we are academics, we do not answer questions about every field that is studied in academia! For answers to questions about Biology, Chemistry, Physics, Math, Computer Science, English, Cognitive Science, Finance, Economics, Politics, etc... you will have to go to their respective Stack Exchange sites. Instead, on Academia we answer questions that are *not* about the content of the field of study: questions about applying to graduate school, about the process of submitting a paper to a journal for publication, about applying to postdoc and faculty positions, about teaching at the university level, and other things like that. Thus, [your question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83373/relevent-change-in-the-finance-field) was outside the scope of this site.

As with the other Stack Exchange sites, you can find out more about the scope of the community in the help center, on the page titled [What topics can I ask about here?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This page lists some of the categories of questions that are welcome here, as well as some of the categories of questions that are not. Every Stack Exchange site has a page like that; you are encouraged to peruse it before posting.

Comment: Thank you finally giving me a straightforward answer. To my knowledge, I was aware that because it was a research type question I was able to post it. As I had seen other post of similarities that had been posted. The exact guidelines that are set up for academia are misleading in a way and are up for interpretation in my opinion. And perhaps having a more clarified and specific list would help clear up future confusion as what is and is not allowed.

Comment: @Lorena Please feel free to propose a change to the "What topics can I ask about page here?" in a new meta post (see [What is meta? How does it work?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) - note that you'll need to [earn a few points first](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)) Best to be specific about what proposed change you have in mind - after all, it's easy to say "This is confusing" but not so easy to come up with a better way!

Comment: As soon as I can obtain the necessary amount of points I will suggest a change. With an explanation on how I find it confusing and how I feel it could be more specified. Thank you again

Answer (score 5):

> To my knowledge, academia is a broad category that covers many topics with education.

Academia.SE is a community that covers a number of topics related to the academic world. Not all the academic topics, though. And the list of accepted topics can be modified with well crafted proposals. I let you judge whether yours is a well-crafted proposal or not.

> So it would seem to be a reasonable conclusion to post a question asking for articles or sites for research on a thread for academia.

We do not substitute advisors, colleagues and research work. And for specialized topics many other communities give suggestions or articles, books etc.

Answer (score 4):

> How can someone ask a question regarding research in academia without being accused of "shopping"?

To take your particular situation as an example:

> How can I find out about recent changes in a particular field?

[A similar question](//academia.stackexchange.com/q/3420/7734) already exists and in fact we have an [entire tag](//academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature-search) for similar questions. However, “ask on Academia SE” is not an answer to this question. Note that this is crucially different from asking for specific resources for your particular field, which would be off-topic – as it is not about academia but about a specific academic field. As a litmus test questions that can only be answered by somebody in your particular subfield are off-topic here (and should be asked on a Stack Exchange pertaining to your field instead).

Moreover, asking for specific resources would be indeed what we call a shopping question, because it effectively asks us to evaluate resources, which is something that we do not like to do as we would like to keep a neutral stance on such questions, there is no definite answer (and what is a good answer is opinion-based), such questions tend to attract tons of answers, and some other problems. As many other Stack Exchanges have similar rules regarding such questions, it is possible that asking for specific resources will not be well received on the Stack Exchange for your field of interest.